# Searching a document with a Scanner object?

Tags: java

I am making a program that reads data from a formatted text document:

> Planetary Data
>
> Planet       Diameter (km)      Mass (kg)      g (m/s^2)
>
> - Mercury           4880         3.30E+23           3.70
> - Venus            12104         4.87E+24           8.87
> - Earth            12756         5.97E+24           9.79
> - Mars              6794         6.24E+23           3.61
> - Jupiter         142984         1.90E+27          24.80
> - Saturn          120536         5.68E+26          10.43
> - Uranus           51118         8.68E+25           8.86
> - Neptune          49352         1.02E+26          11.17

In a text file it's a little more pretty but basically it is a four column document with info one number falling into each column. I am using the scanner class to try to read only the last column of numbers, but can't find an easy way to do it with out using a ton of nextLine() calls. Is there a better way to search just for those doubles, and pull them into an array with a scanner?

This code will compile but I get a mismatch error as soon as I run it.

```
public static double [] getGravity()throws IOException{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("PlanetaryData.txt"));
    double [] getGrav = new double[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        getGrav[i] = inFile.nextDouble();
        getGrav[i] /= 10;
        System.out.println(getGrav[i]);
    }
    return getGrav;
}
```

Comment: This is a *Computer Science* stack exchange. I would refer your question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah. I will put it up there. I assumed AP Computer Science questions might be relevant here. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You can see in the tour: http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour that even though it's CS class, does not imply it's relevant. Note also that most AP Computer Science classes have very little material about Computer Science, and is mostly programming (at least in my experience).

Comment: It seems that you only care about the part of each line following its last whitespace character. So do just that: find the index of the last whitespace character, take the substring after this index, and parse it to a double: `double value = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

1) your data file has a few lines of header you need to skip them carefully first. Your listing includes some blank lines and then some HTML formatting, so it is not clear how the actual data file looks like.

2) your data consists of 4 columns, but your code is trying to read 8 doubles -- this is wrong. Also the columns are of different types: word double double double, thus you need to read it in such order. Something like this:

```
// .. do some header skipping here
ArrayList<Double> gravity = new ArrayList<>(8);
while (inFile.hasNext()){ // try to read one data line
    inFile.next(); // skip name
    inFile.nextDouble(); // skip diameter
    inFile.nextDouble(); // skip mass
    gravity.add(inFile.nextDouble()/10); // gravity
}
return gravity.toArray();
```